# How to copy contents from one object to another Js

Tags: javascript

I have an obejct:

```
obj1 = {
id: 123,
name: "ABC test",
desc: "SPme test sdesctiption",
data: [{name:"data1"}],
createdBy: "Some person",
updatedBy: "Some persone22"
}
```

Now when we edit the details of this data from client side, we need to update only those fields from the object that has been changed.
ex:

```
updatedObj = {
    id: 123,
    name: "ABC12222222 test", // changed
    desc: "SPme test sdesctiption",
    data: [{name:"data1"}],
    createdBy: "Some person",
    updatedBy: "Some persone22"
    }
```

In above case I only want to change the name, but this data can be dynamic and based on what user changes, we need to update only thoe fields in the `obj1`

I tried :

```
newObj = Object.assign(obj1, {updatedObj})
```

but this inserts all new object inside obj1. I tried using Shallow copy of objects but that did not quite work.

any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Example of coding [difference between 2 objects](https://gomakethings.com/getting-the-differences-between-two-objects-with-vanilla-js/).

Comment: Don't put `{}` around `updatedObj`. It's already an object, you don't have to wrap it again.

Comment: Why does `updatedObj` have all the fields instead of just the changed fields?

Comment: You'll need to create a [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy). There are various ways to do this. The most common way is outlined in the previous link. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/10601203) is a StackOverflow answer that goes a bit more in-depth on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since updatedObj have all the fields instead of just the changed fields

```
newObj = updatedObj
```